# Sort collection in mongodb based on nearest date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

my dateObj is like "2021.05.08 AD at 21:44:02", is it possible to order the collection base on nearest date?
for ex -
expected output

```
[
{
    "setting": {
        "bill": "300",
        "dateTime": "2021.05.28 AD at 14:29:49"
    }
},
{
    "setting": {
        "dateTime": "2021.05.09 AD at 03:09:37",
        "bill": "300"
    }
},
{
    "setting": {
        "dateTime": "2021.05.03 AD at 16:46:25",
        "bill": "900"
    }
}
]
```

> Input JSON data

```
[
{
    "setting": {
        "dateTime": "2021.05.03 AD at 16:46:25",
        "bill": "900"
    }
},
{
    "setting": {
        "dateTime": "2021.05.09 AD at 03:09:37",
        "bill": "300"
    }
},
{
    "setting": {
        "bill": "300",
        "dateTime": "2021.05.28 AD at 14:29:49"
    }
}
]
```

> Query-

```
router.get('/getPost',async(req,res)=>{
collection.find().sort({'setting.dateTime':-1}).exec().then(doc=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        'status':true,
        'message': doc
    })
})
})
```

However it's not sorting like which is nearest post created according to current time.
What's wrong i'm doing?

Comment: Please show your code for javascript (typo sorry!)

Comment: I'm not sure if this dateTime has an accepted format `2021.05.28 AD at 14:29:49`. Could you confirm if your dateTime is typeof Date()?

Comment: i'm just passing it from android (Connected with Api). Should i change format?

Comment: @BhaskarJha you can save it as ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` and date type.